# How to return the first chunk of either numerics or letters from a string?

Tags: java, regex, string

For example, if I had (-> means return):

```
aBc123afa5  ->  aBc

168dgFF9g  ->  168

1GGGGG  ->  1
```

How can I do this in Java? I assume it's something regex related but I'm not great with regex and so not too sure how to implement it (I could with some thought but I have a feeling it would be 5-10 lines long, and I think this could be done in a one-liner).

Thanks

Comment: did you want the text after `->`?

Comment: 3rd one case cant understand properly

Comment: yep sorry, I want the text after ->

Comment: Would this work for you? `/^([a-zA-Z]+|[0-9]+)/`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String myString = "aBc123afa5";
String extracted = myString.replaceAll("^([A-Za-z]+|\\d+).*$", "$1");
```

View the [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/cT2qW3) and the [live code demonstration](http://jdoodle.com/a/7o)!

To use `Matcher.group()` and reuse a `Pattern` for efficiency:

```
// Class
private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^([A-Za-z]+|\\d+).*$");

// Your method
{
    String myString = "aBc123afa5";
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(myString);
    if(matcher.matches())
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Note: `/^([A-Za-z]+|\d+).*$` and `/^([A-Za-z]+|\d+)/` both works in similar efficiency. On regex101 you can compare the matcher debug logs to find out this.

Answer (score 1):

Without using regex, you can do this:

```
String string = "168dgFF9g";
String chunk = "" + string.charAt(0);
boolean searchDigit = Character.isDigit(string.charAt(0));
for (int i = 1; i < string.length(); i++) {
  boolean isDigit = Character.isDigit(string.charAt(i));
  if (isDigit == searchDigit) {
    chunk += string.charAt(i);
  } else {
    break;
  }
}
System.out.println(chunk);
```

Comment: This case (no pun intended) would have been better using regex rather than a loop, and I would like to note that line two would be optimal when using `String chunk = Character.toString( string.charAt(0) );`.

Comment: Yeah, right. This is just an alternative solution, since the OP is not that comfortable with regex.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String prefix(String s) {
    return s.replaceFirst("^(\\d+|\\pL+|).*$", "$1");
}
```

where

```
\\d  = digit
\\pL = letter
postfix + = one or more
|    = or
^    = begin of string
$    = end of string
$1   = first group `( ... )`
```

An empty alternative (last `|`) ensures that `(...)` is always matched, and always a replace happens. Otherwise the original string would be returned.

Comment: Will the use of `.replaceFirst()` instead of `.replaceAll()` from my solution enhance performance? I've always had a tendency to use `.replaceAll()` in my code so I'm curious about it.

Comment: Here you want to take one time a (starting) string out of the hole. And in fact throw the rest away. If you see a `"^...$"` it is clear the entirety is matched, and only `replaceFirst` makes sense. But yeah, always that small decision to take care of.